# Why is it saying my component is not defined?

Tags: reactjs

Why am I getting the error component not defined. Am I not declaring it in the first line of code ???? Also is it ok to put const in the constructor. I get an error when I put it somewhere else. Thanks in advance!!!

```
class AboutPanelForm extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
      const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

      const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
      const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
          }

      render() {
      return (
        <>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
            Launch demo modal
          </Button>

          <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </>
      );
      }
    }

    render(<AboutPanelForm />);
```

Comment: which component is not defined? when you use React hooks, you should use functional component, if you want to use class component, you should do state `this.state` ...and it is okay to put const in the constructor. Can you show the full code, and show us the error too?

Comment: Among other problems in your code, did you `export` your component?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `Component` is not defined, yes, you need to import it from react at the top of your file, usually something like --

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Also, using `const` in the constructor means that your functions are only visible in the constructor scope. If you want to use them elsewhere in your class, you should define them with `this`. (like `this.handleClose`)

With the functions that you have though, it makes more sense to define them outside of the constructor completely, like

```
constructor() {
// code
}

handleClose() {
 // your function
}

render() {
 // render
}
```

and then bind them in the constructor:

```
this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
```